# Rotate 180 degree for all app

Tags: apps, settings, screen, orientation

is possible to rotate screen 180 degree?

I want this orientatnion for all apps, because my touch screen is crashed and isn't working good on bottom.

Misrosoft lumia 535 WP10

Comment: 180 degress? you mean, upside down?

Comment: yea i want upside down screen

Comment: Better replace the touch screen

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, **No it's not possible**. :/

Comment: Not possible because no one has made an app to control rotation... or not possible because no app is possible with current API allowances?

Comment: We don't have API for it. Maybe MS will think and about that i future