# Rotate Screen in Windows Phone 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-650

Using an app like [Ultimate Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate&hl=en) in android I can control global rotation - locking or unlocking 0/90/180/270 degrees of rotation...

... as well as applying individual app settings. Locking certain apps to portrait or landscape - or applying individual settings as needed.

Does anything like this exist on Windows Phone 10?

If it doesn't exist, is it theoretically possible via a home brewed app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate 180 degree for all app](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13775/rotate-180-degree-for-all-app)

Comment: That's simply 180. This is expanded and more all encompassing. That question is: `Is ther an app that does A?` - this question is: `Is there an app that does A/B/C/D? Or is there the ability to program those myself?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for app developers to change or lock global rotation of the phone, so you won't find any apps that are doing this in the store.

You might be able to do this with a homebrew-app, but you'll need an interop unlock on your phone to do this. I would recommend the xda-developers forums for further inquiries.

Comment: I hadn't seen anything definitive besides this and the other similar question. I'll have to look into XDA when I have a little more time.